# Rails route returning wrong data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails api which has a model post which has_many comments and vice versa. I'm using nested routes.

I'm trying to get all the comments for a particular post using the route:

```
/posts/:post_id/comments
```

I send a get http request to

```
http://localhost:3000/posts/1/comments
```

But it's returning all comments in the database no matter what post id I pass in the url.

Here is what my routes look like and if you need to see more code let me know.

```
    post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                  POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                  PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                  DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
            posts GET    /posts(.:format)                            posts#index
                  POST   /posts(.:format)                            posts#create
         new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                        posts#new
        edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
             post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
                  PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                  DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#destroy
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Perhaps the code that retrieves the comments.

Comment: Could you share controller actions involved?

Comment: Sorry the code is just default scaffold controllers. So index for comment is getting: `@comments = Comment.all`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `index` action of your `CommentsController`, make sure that while fetching the records of `comments` you specify the `post_id`, i.e., you get all the comments for a particular `post_id`:

```
def index
  #...
  @comments = Comment.where(post_id: params[:post_id])
  #...
end
```

Comment: worked a treat! I thought resources set up the index correctly to take params.